# Add type parameter constraint to prevent abstract classes

Tags: c#

Is it possible to restrict a type parameter to concrete implementations of an abstract class, if those implementations don't have default constructors?

For example, if I have:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    private Animal()
    {
    }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        // ...
    }

  // ...
}


public class Penguin : Animal
{
    // ...
}


public class Chimpanzee : Animal
{
    // ...
}
```

And I also have the following class:

```
public class ZooPen<T>
   where T : Animal
{
    // ...
}
```

I would like to allow `new ZooPen<Penguin>()` and `new ZooPen<Chimpanzee>()`, but I would like to disallow `new ZooPen<Animal>()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need this restriction? Is it to create the subclasses using a constructor you get by reflection? If so, why not just add a runtime check that makes it clear *why* the restriction is there instead of a potentially confusing compile-time error from the hacks proposed.

Comment: I agree with millimoose. The restriction smells bad to me. If you need to create new instances within the Zoo Pen, then you can make it take a factory as a constructor argument.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I'm starting to agree.  millimoose is right that the class with the type parameter is instantiating the subclasses via reflection.  Anyway I'm rethinking how I'm going to handle this, so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish what you're asking for.

```
abstract class Animal
{
    readonly string Name;
    Animal() { }
    public Animal(string name) { Name = name; }
}

abstract class Animal<T> : Animal where T : Animal<T>
{
    public Animal(string name) : base(name) { }
}

class Penguin : Animal<Penguin>
{
    public Penguin() : base("Penguin") { }
}

class Chimpanzee : Animal<Chimpanzee>
{
    public Chimpanzee() : base("Chimpanzee") { }
}

class ZooPen<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
}

class Example
{
    void Usage()
    {
        var penguins = new ZooPen<Penguin>();
        var chimps = new ZooPen<Chimpanzee>();
        //this line will not compile
        //var animals = new ZooPen<Animal>();
    }
}
```

Anyone maintaining this code will probably be a bit confused, but it does exactly what you want.

Comment: You could also use an interface.  (`where T : Animal, ITypedAnimal<T>`)

Answer (score 14):

You can add the `new()` constraint, which will require that the class not be abstract and have a default constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I am facing is that the concrete classes do not have default constructors.

Comment: @Andrew: Then the CLR type system cannot help you.  Sorry.

Comment: @SLaks that's what I was afraid of.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ZooPen<T> where T : Animal
{
    public ZooPen()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsAbstract)
            throw new ArgumentException(typeof(T).Name + " must be non abstract class");
    }
}
```