# How can I derive a class nested inside a partial class?

Tags: c#, derived-class, nested-class, partial-classes

If I have an abstract class nested inside a partial container class nested inside another class, how can I derive classes from the base class? I would think the following would work, but it says BaseClass isn't accessible due to protection level. I need the derived classes to be private though.

And before anyone tells me what a bad structure this is, [this is why I might need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197623/how-can-i-derive-classes-from-a-base-class-that-is-encapsulated-in-a-manager-cla).

```
    class SingletonClass
    {
        public static partial class ContainerClass
        {
            abstract class BaseClass
            {

            }
        }
    }

    static partial class ContainerClass
    {
        class DerivedClass : BaseClass
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: make your SingletonClass partial and nest second part of your ContainerClass inside SingletonClass.

Comment: Your related question doesn't justify your design decision. It is still a bad idea. If you want to inherit, then probably the base class shouldn't be nested. I recommend not to do this. Consider redesigning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code does not compile because there are two different `ContainerClass` types. One is a "normal" class and the other is nested in `SingletonClass`. If there are no namespace involved then the full name of the first is `SingletonClass.ContainerClass` while the full name of the second is `ContainerClass` (i.e., two different types).

To do what you want you need to make `SingletonClass` partial also:

```
partial class SingletonClass
{
    public static partial class ContainerClass
    {
        abstract class BaseClass
        {

        }
    }
}

partial class SingletonClass
{
    public static partial class ContainerClass
    {
        class DerivedClass : BaseClass
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work, but I figured out a more elegant solution to my overall problem.